# Module 'test' has no attribute 'variable'

Tags: python, global-variables, spyder

I have two files:

testons.py (an empty file)

test_main.py:

```
import testons

print(testons.gamma)
```

I run test_main.py with spyder run button which returns me an error "module 'testons' has no attribute 'gamma'" (this is normal I didn't defined this variable).

Then in Python console inside spyder I do: testons.gamma=2.

And I correctly have:

```
print(testons.gamma) # It returns me 2 as expected.
```

However if after I re-run test_main.py with run button from spyder I still obtain the same error.

Why is it the case ? My variable is supposed to be defined now ! Everything behave as if python cleared my variable...?

Comment: How are you running test_main.py?  What do you mean by the "python console"?

Comment: @John Gordon I am running it with the run button in spyder software. I am talking about the python console of spyder. Maybe my issue is software related ?

Comment: I suspect that clicking the "run" button from Spyder starts a fresh context, and it does not remember the earlier modification you made to `testons.gamma`.